# Can I get a Shared memory segment to be a Fortran COMMON block?

Tags: fortran, shared-memory

I have the pleasure of modernizing an older mixed Fortran and C code base. One of the neat features of this code base is that the Fortran gets transpiled into C, and then compiled into executables.

I'm working on getting the Fortran source in the code base to compile with the Intel Fortran compiler, and the C source withe the Intel C compiler.

The Fortran code features a named common block that appears in many, many .f files:

```
COMMON / SHCOM / IVAR1, IARY(40), IVAR2, ...
```

In the original, transpiled program, the C code actually allocates a SysV-style shared memory segment (using `shmget()` and `shmat()`), and assigns the address of the shared memory segment to a C variable `shcom_`. Because all Fortran is transpiled to C, and the common block name and the C variable end up as the same symbol name, the common block is in the shared memory segment.

Is there some way to do this with Fortran compiled into .o files, and C compiled into .o files? That is, can I trick the compiler into letting the comon block be in a SysV shared memory segment?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want this common block to be in a shared memory seg? You give no reason for this requirement above, and if you don't need it life gets much simpler.

Comment: You don't want do rewrite the common blocks to modules?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch - way too much legacy code to do that, I think.